# Maven Build error: There is not EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment

Tags: java, spring, maven, amazon-web-services

New to Java and Spring framework. I have written a webservice and I'm trying to compile it successfuly, there are no errors showing on the IDE, but when I try to do a Maven Build...

I get this error message when I'm trying to do a build locally on my dev machine and debug in Spring STS. I found a git repo with the instructions to create an access.properties file in the project and put the Region tag in there, like so: **cloud.aws.region.static=US_EAST_1**, but I also added these: **cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey,
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey**

But even after doing that I still get the error above.

I then added a POM dependency for: **spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure**

But still the same error.

The error appears in various manners, referring to EC2 and S3, etc..., my project is only related to Redshift.

I am new to Spring STS and Java, so not sure if I'm missing registering the prop file somewhere else. However I don't have any other kinds of errors except this one.

Comment: How does your POM look like?

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DAOlJz-7TUWDlRVTlsWU5aZ0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Here's the entire project zipped up for download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DAOlJz-7TUOWNJQmUySDBNODg/view?usp=sharing  ,  not much to it. The maven GOAL setting in Spring is "package" and that's how I try to build it.